# Audio widget and graphs not displayed in the same region in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter, librosa

I want to show multiple audio files via a player and a waveform in jupyter. Problem is: first all of the audio-widgets get displayed and THEN the waveforms follow. This is easy to ignore when only one of them is plotted, but after 10 or more files it becomes confusing. Can i somehow tie the widget to the plot like the program flow actually implies?

```
from IPython.display import Audio
import librosa as lr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

local_targets = ["files/sound1.wav", "files/sound2.wav", "files/sound3.wav"]

for i in range(len(local_targets)):

   wav_data_lr, sample_rate = lr.load(local_targets[i], mono=True, sr=16000, duration=10)
   # Audio widget
   display(Audio(wav_data_lr, rate=16000))

   plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
   plt.plot(wav_data_lr)
   plt.xlim([0, len(wav_data_lr)])
```

Output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Kc3.jpg

Comment: Why don't you just set the audio widget after the waveform creation graph? `plt.plot(wav_data_lr);display(Audio(wav_data_lr, rate=16000))`

Comment: @r-beginners that changes nothing. Have you tried it?

Comment: @r-beginners adding "plt.xlim([0, len(wav_data_lr)])" and "plt.show()" changes the behavior and is the solution to the problem, thank you